# Should we still use Tomcat 8.0 (superseded)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

Should we still use Tomcat 8.0, as it is marked **superseded** and replaced by Tomcat 8.5 ?

References :

- [List of Tomcat versions](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [Details on Tomcat 8.x](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html#Apache_Tomcat_8.x)

Extracts from https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html#Apache_Tomcat_8.x :

> - It (*Tomcat 8.5*) was created in March 2016.
> - Tomcat 8.5 is thought as a replacement for Tomcat 8.0.

Other links :

- [Migrating from 8.0.x to 8.5.x](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html)
- [Tomcat 8.0 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html)
- [Tomcat 8.5 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html)

Comment: I think this is a good time to upgrade to version **Tomcat 8.5**

Answer (score 2):

One major issue to consider when using a legacy version of something is whether or not it will continue to be supported with regards to things like bug support, security, etc.  This matters because if you discover something like a bug or security hole, you want the means to deal with it.  The [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) has this to say about legacy support:

> Please note that although we offer downloads and documentation of older releases, such as Apache Tomcat 7.x, we strongly encourage users to use the latest stable version of Apache Tomcat whenever possible. We recognize that upgrading across major versions may not be a trivial task, and some support is still offered on the mailing list for users of old versions. However, because of the community-driven support approach, the older your version, fewer people will be interested or able to support you.

If you want to minimize the risk of not having full support if you need it, then you should use the latest verison of Tomcat (`9.x` as of the time this answer was written).

Comment: Note that at the time this answer was written, Tomcat 9 has not been voted as stable. It is still considered to be "beta" and may not be appropriate for a production environment (yet).

Answer (score 1):

[EOL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html) for Tomcat 8.0 is announced to be on june 2018. The changelog you saw tells there are no incompatibilities and some improvements (they basically added something and removed clutter. BIO connector removal throws a warning and defaults to NIO connector so it won't fail).

You must test first, but I'd say it's safe and wise to move to Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm adding the link : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the tomcat instance is used you might consider below as critical part when it comes to the decision if it should be used or not:

> **End of life** for Apache Tomcat 8.0.x The Apache Tomcat team announces
>   that support for Apache Tomcat 8.0.x will end on 30 June 2018.
>
> This means that after 30 June 2018:
>
> - releases from the 8.0.x branch are highly unlikely bugs affecting only
> - the 8.0.x branch will not be addressed security vulnerability reports
> - will not be checked against the 8.0.x branch

[Source link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html)